# select where age between 35 - 50 from date of birth

Tags: mysql

Hi i want to select data from table where age between 30-50 from date of birth column.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob1 AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age, * 
   from tbl_travelins) as tbl_travelins
WHERE Age >= 30 AND Age < 50
```

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: query not working

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER) - CAST(dob1 AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age, * from tbl_travelins) as tbl' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Try using `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_travelins
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob1, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 49;
```

Comment: I can't see your actual data, so I can't really help.  But note that your `WHERE` clause should use numbers, not text, i.e. `BETWEEN 0 AND 54`